# Why status is Not Opted In and .sfmc_pushEnabled() is true?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, ios, mobilepush-ios

I have a problem with opt out, when I print the `MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_pushEnabled()` this returns `true`, but when I go in portal the same DeviceID is showing this informations:

`Status: Not Opted In`

`Opt-Out Font: ServiceFeedback`

`Opt-Out Date: 07/10/2020 11:06`

`Opt in Origin: MOBILE_OPT_IN`

What I do wrong?

Comment: This is almost always a cert issue.  Please verify that you have followed the implementation instructions.  If you feel that you have done this then open a support case through your support representative.

Comment: I tested the same cert in another service(OneSignal), the push is sending to iPhone :/

Comment: That does not matter.  This is almost certainly a cert issue.  Open a case.  We can go back and forth here or you can get this resolved very quickly.  Up to you.